# Reading an infinite data in Python and feeding to another external process

Tags: linux, python, pipe, devices, random

I am using Python to read data from a TRNG (true random number generator) device, and I want to feed this data to an external utility (e.g., dieharder). The data itself is an indefinite stream, but its bitrate is not very fast (60 Kbps). Is there a way to achieve that? Basically, I want to feed my data to a 3rd-party tool as if it was the output data from /dev/urandom.

I tried to continuously write my data to a regular file and then feed that file's output to dieharder, but it errorred out due to EOF. If my understanding is correct device files like /dev/random implement a "read block" until they get more data, so a 3rd-party tool will wait. I need something similar. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you get the EOF when reading (I can't imagine getting an EOF when writing to a regular file), this is so because whatever device produces the random input data generates this EOF, or rather the device driver does. This has nothing to do with Python, and everything with the way the TRNG device is configured and accessed. As long as you don't say what device that is and how you read the data, that's all that can be said.

Comment: Use a pipe device (fifo) if you need a name on the file system, or pipe the output if your python script to the other program as in `your_python_script | other_program`. Both will block on reads.